# CSS styling input box and a href link with same class

Tags: html, css

I am newbie on css and always priority of classes in CSS is complex to me.

I want to convert links to buttons with and did it successfully and I want to expand and apply the style to input[type="submit"] input[type="submit"] and I did it again successfully.
But my problem is when I want to change color of style doesn't apply to button.

My CSS sample:

```
.btn,input[type="submit"],input[type="button"] {
    color: #ffffff;
    cursor: pointer;
    line-height: 1em;
    margin: 5ox 3px 8px 0;
    outline: medium none;
    overflow: visible;
    position: relative;
    transition: all 300ms ease-in 0s;
    white-space: nowrap;
      /*Transition*/
    -webkit-transition: All 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: All 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: All 0.5s ease;
    -ms-transition: All 0.5s ease;
    transition: All 0.5s ease;
    background-color: red;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 7px 10px;
}

.btn:hover,input[type="submit"]:hover,input[type="button"]:hover{
    background-color: #F27C6B;
}

.btn_purple{
    background-color: purple;
}

.btn_purple:hover{
    background-color: #B59DCC;
}

input{
 border: none;   
}
```

My html sample:

```
<!--red-->
<a href="#" class="btn" >test</a>
<!--purple-->
<a href="#" class="btn btn_purple" >test</a>

<!--red-->
<input type="button" value="test »"/>
<!--purple-->
<input type="button" class="btn_purple" value="test »"/>

<!--purple with btn class-->
<input type="button" class="btn btn_purple" value="test »"/>
```

and For making my point clear, I create a demo in js fiddle. Demo Link: http://jsfiddle.net/2dwycka8/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can be more specific with the `.btn-purple` class and declare it like this:
`.btn.btn_purple, input[type=button].btn_purple {...}`

Updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2dwycka8/4/)

Answer (score 1):

You Can Use `!important` in `.btn_purple` class

```
.btn_purple{
    background-color: #9966CC !important;
}
```

jsfiddle [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2dwycka8/3/)